# how to show one value if there have same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show just 1 value if there is have same value,
forexample

in my record like this..

---

```
Jumlah
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
7
```

nad I want to show for my view is

```
5
6
7
```

for my SQL Code is `select year(tgl_moc) as tahun from rol_tb_form1 group by tahun order by tahun desc`

how to make that in C# ASP.NET MVC

sorry for my bad englis

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: can you make me a full code for example please @lamandy

Comment: see below for answer

Comment: you are doing group by with that column(tahun) so you shouldn't be getting duplicates.
For c# what data repo are you using?

Comment: yeah, But I dont understand Use GroupBy in C#, can you make some example for GroupBy, @MurtazaTahirAli

Comment: From your query, you are getting tahun, where does jumlah come from? By jumlah, do you mean the number of students with the same tahun?

Comment: thats just example for year in SQL I want to make like that but in ASP.NET MVC @lamandy

Comment: How you get the jumlah in the first place? In that query, use `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is already in list then use below code

```
listOfYears.GroupBy(s => s).Select(g => g);
```

and if you are fetching from database then

```
from y in listOfYears
          group y by y into g
          select g.Key;
```

Comment: My pleasure it helped you